# Как сортировать массив по конкретному значению?

Tags: php, php7

Мне нужно отсортировать массив по значению, к примеру:

```
$a = [
0 => ['entity' => 1, ...],
1 => ['entity' => 0, ...],
2 => ['entity' => 1, ...],
3 => ['entity' => 0, ...],
4 => ['entity' => 1, ...],
]
```

Чтобы элементы массива у которых 'entity' => 1 были в начале массива, а все остальные элементы после них.

Comment: Пример не очень понятный, можно более нормальным пример исходного массива и что должно быть в конце?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Можно использовать [usort](https://www.php.net/manual/ru/function.usort.php) для сортировки массива по значениям используя пользовательскую функцию для сравнения элементов

```
$a = [
    0 => ['entity' => 1, 'test' => 1],
    1 => ['entity' => 0,  'test' => 2],
    2 => ['entity' => 1,  'test' => 3],
    3 => ['entity' => 0,  'test' => 4],
    4 => ['entity' => 1,  'test' => 5],
];

usort($a, function($prev, $curr) use ($a) {
    return $prev['entity'] < $curr['entity'];
});

print_r($a);
```

output:

```
Array
    (
        [0] => Array
            (
                [entity] => 1
                [test] => 1
            )
        [1] => Array
            (
                [entity] => 1
                [test] => 3
            )
        [2] => Array
            (
                [entity] => 1
                [test] => 5
            )
        [3] => Array
            (
                [entity] => 0
                [test] => 2
            )
        [4] => Array
            (
                [entity] => 0
                [test] => 4
            )
    )
```

Comment: Отлично, спасибо большое. А если массив содержит не массивы, а stdClass объекты?

Comment: @dukir значит работаете со stdClass объектами xDDD